# Access an element's parent with PHP's SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm iterating through a set of SimpleXML objects, and I can't figure out how to access each object's parent node.  Here's what I want:

```
$divs = simplexml->xpath("//div");
foreach ($divs as $div)
{
   $parent_div = $div->get_parent_node(); // Sadly, there's no such function.
}
```

Seems like there must be a fairly easy way to do this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could run a simple XPath query to get it:

```
$parent_div = $div->xpath("parent::*");
```

And as this is Simplexml and it only has element and attribute nodes and a parent node can only be an element and never an attribute, the abbreviated syntax can be used:

```
$parent_div = $div->xpath("..");
```

(via: [*Common Xpath Cheats - SimpleXML Type Cheatsheet (Feb 2013; by hakre)*](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simplexml-type-cheatsheet/) )

Comment: Will this method **always** return one parent? I'm noticing it returns an array.

Comment: Yes, xpath returns an array, so you'd need to suffix `[0]??null` onto the end to get the actual node, or null if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 20):

> `$div->get_parent_node(); // Sadly, there's no such function.`

Note that you can extend SimpleXML to make it so. For example:

```
class my_xml extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function get_parent_node()
    {
        return current($this->xpath('parent::*'));
    }
}
```

And now all you have to do is modify the code you use to create your SimpleXMLElement in the first place:

```
$foo = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo/>');
// becomes
$foo = new my_xml('<foo/>');

$foo = simplexml_load_string('<foo/>');
// becomes
$foo = simplexml_load_string('<foo/>', 'my_xml');

$foo = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml');
// becomes
$foo = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml', 'my_xml');
```

The best part is that SimpleXML will automatically and transparently return `my_xml` objects for this document, so you don't have to change anything else, which makes your `get_parent_node()` method chainable:

```
// returns $grandchild's parent's parent
$grandchild->get_parent_node()->get_parent_node();
```

Comment: Awesome, Josh...very illuminating.  I'm sure I'll be using this in the future for all sorts of things!

Answer (score 6):

If memory serves, an `xpath()` call returns one or more `SimpleXMLElements`. If that's the case, then you may be able to use something like:

```
$div->xpath( '..' );
# or
$div->xpath( 'parent::*' );
```