# get parent elements in xml with simplexml in php?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

with `$element->children()` i cant get all the child elements of current element.

but how can i get all the parent elements for current element with simplexml?

lets say it looks like this:

```
<entity id=1>
   <name>apple</name>
   <entities>
      <entity id=2>
         <name>mac</name>
         <entities>
            <entity id=3>
               <name>safari</name>
            </entity>
         </entities>
      </entity>
   </entities>
</entity>
```

if my current `$element` is `id=3`, i want to get the mac and apple entity ids.

is this possible with simplexml cause i cant find any function allowing me to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174263/access-an-elements-parent-with-phps-simplexml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $element->xpath("ancestor::entity/@id")
```

Comment: could you explain "ancestor::entity/@id" for me?

Comment: It selects the `id` attribute of all ancestor `<entry>` nodes. Learn XPath, it's really not hard. ;)