# How to get the value of an element that it is in a higher level of where your xPath is inside your existing foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am creating a PHP script that gets many RSS and displays them on the page sorted by date. My problem is that I need to show the name of the blog and the link to it but they are in a higher level in the structure (as below) of where I get the post's title, link, content, images etc.

My question is how can I easily add the blog's title and link without using a strpos maybe in the link of the post to get the info ?

the rss structure

```
<rss><chanell><title><link><other info for the blog><item>here goes the elements of the post</item><item>and so on</item>
```

and the main piece of the code

```
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/rss/channel//item'));
}
.
.
.
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo "the title of the blog and the link"
echo $entry->title; //this is the title of the item
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Access an element's parent with PHP's SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174263/access-an-elements-parent-with-phps-simplexml)

Comment: This platform is not suited to that kind of help, I would suggest a BB like PHPbuilder for this type of help (I am also there as many others).