# How to create the full path to an element when parsing a XML-file?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a link to an XML file.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com');
```

```
<shop>
    <name>Shop name</name>
    <company>Company name</company>
    <url>https://example.com/shop</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop2</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop3</url>
    <currencies>
        <currency>
            <name>XXX</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>YYY</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>ZZZ</name>
        </currency>
    </currencies>
</shop>
```

Using this function I get all the names of the elements and their quantity:

```
$elements = [];
foreach ($xml->xpath('//*') as $element) {
    $name = $element->getName();
    $elements[$name] = ($elements[$name] ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

This results in an array like this:

```
    [shop] => 1
    [name] => 4
    [company] => 1
    [url] => 3
    [currencies] => 1
    [currency] => 3
```

How can I add to this array, in addition to the name and quantity, the full path of this element from the parent?

It should look something like this:

```
    [shop] => [
      'count' => 1,
      'path' => 'shop',
    ]
    [name] => [
      'count' => 4,
      'path' => 'shop.name',
    ]
    [company] => [
      'count' => 1,
      'path' => 'shop.company',
    ]
    [url] => [
      'count' => 3,
      'path' => 'shop.url',
    ]
    [currencies] => [
      'count' => 1,
      'path' => 'shop.currencies',
    ]
    [currency] => [
      'count' => 3,
      'path' => 'shop.currencies.currency',
    ]
```

Comment: My approach would be to walk up the path of parent elements. This would be easier if you used PHP DOM - because that gives you direct access to the parent node of an element. SimpleXML doesn't, but it can be achieved with a further xpath selection, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174282/1427878

Comment: Your current requirement does not make that much sense to begin with though. `[name] => 4` - what you counted here, are all the `name` elements - that one directly below `shop`, and those inside `currencies`-> `currency`. So getting a count of `4`, with path `'path' => 'shop.name'` - that does not really make sense. That is the path for the first of those `name` elements only, the other three should have `shop.currencies.currency.name` - but you would have to record them under a different key in your result array to begin with then.